# How to design interfaces for complex query in DAO(Should we always design generic interfaces for DAO)?

Tags: java, dao, mybatis

I was told to write generic interface for DAO When I first learning coding. It's not recommend to design a interface "findByName" and something like that, because findBy**Name** related with business logic( the name). I used Criteria of hibernate to write generic interfaces, it worked well. While I used mybatis recently, it's hard to keep the interfaces generic because I had to write sql myself. I write many methods like this:

```
T find(QueryTuple queryTuple);

public class QueryTuple {
    private String key;
    private Object value;
    //This is an enum
    private CompareOperqator operator;
    // setter and getter
}
```

And I invoked the find method like this:

```
find(new QueryTuple("name", "tom", CompareOperqator.EQUAL));
find(new QueryTuple("gender", "m", CompareOperqator.EQUAL));
```

However if I want to write some complex queries, I can not keep the interface so "generic", I have to write interface such as findByXXAndXX.

Is it really good to keep so called "generic"? I found Spring data also support interface like findByXX.

Comment: The mybatis API is a generic DAO already: it allows you to define any kind of query and execute it. The point of a DAO is to be non-generic, and encapsulate the query creation logic into functional reusable methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was told to write generic interface for DAO

IMO, you shouldn't reinvent a wheel, things like this are all implemented already.

But if you want, use [**Builder pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). It can look like this:

```
dao.query("person").with("name", "tom").with("gender", "m").find();
```

Notice that I don't pass instances of QueryTuple, but just arguments to construct those. Also it's not type safe, just the simplest implementation.

`with()` method can assume `CompareOperator.EQUAL` and ignoring case by default, and there also should be a version with third and fourth arguments:

```
public QueryBuilder with(String property, String value) {
    return with(property, value, CompareOperator.EQUAL, true);
}

public QueryBuilder with(String property, String value, 
                         CompareOperator compareOperator, 
                         boolean ignoreCase) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the build pattern is a better way! You also think the interface should be generic,  but how do you think [Spring-data-jpa](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)? Spring data jpa support the interface like "findByEmailAddressAndLastname", does the "EmailAddressAndLastname" generic? So I wander which is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's MBG(mybatis generator). I reinvented a wheel just like @scriptin said. It's very convenient to use xxxByExample, and is easy to extend if necessary!